# How fast do you need to throw a wooden stick for it to be lethal with bare hands?

Tags: internal-consistency

how hard does one need to throw (With bare hands) in order for a lowly stick to become lethal ? Also taking into account distances, both close and long distances. Finally how much strength would be needed and subsequently can it be done by human physical means ?

Comment: Hardness is not necessary; at sufficient velocity, *grass* (dried grass, anyway, i.e. "straw") is lethal. Wooden spears can certainly be lethal when wielded by humans without being made out of exotic materials. The answer is going to be heavily dependent on the stick's mass, how it impacts, and whether or not the point of impact is sharpened.

Comment: You might need to define "stick" - you'd have to throw a twig very hard to do any damage, but you could crack someone's skull with a wooden club. You could also stab someone with a wooden knife with little effort, or you could just trap them under a giant log. How big is a "stick", and does it have to be a "natural stick", or can it be sharpened/modified? Does a "throw" have to be unassisted, or are we talking about any form of wooden projectile?

Comment: Density and shape are also important. If your stick is insufficiently dense or not aerodynamic, it will be slowed by air resistance to the point that it's not lethal... and the harder you throw it, the faster it will slow down.

Comment: @NuclearWang I was picturing a relatively dense and aerodynamic wooden blunt object...perhaps something like a boomerang. I was wondering if I were to pick up said item and throw it as hard as I could at someone under what conditions would I be able to kill them if at all.

Comment: @Cadence Let's say a war boomerang for simplicity sake. I was to throw one at someone as hard as humanly possible, under what circumstances would it be lethal if at all.

Comment: Decades ago a child was killed at a little league baseball game by a ball thrown by another child. Elephants can hurl large branches or tree trunks with lethal forces.  An adult human would be stronger than a 10-year-old but weaker than an elephant, but could throw a wooden war club with possibly lethal force.

Answer (score 5):

Boomerangs are lethal.  They're thrown without leverage or stored energy.

A *baseball* can be lethal -- if you get beaned with a fastball and aren't wearing a helmet, you could die of the resulting injuries (most don't, but it's part of the reason for batting helmets).  A boomerang, due to its shape, is a little easier to throw at high speeds -- 30-50 m/s, say -- and is heavy enough that it can kill a human (though they're really intended for small game hunting).

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for !

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on how big the stick is, what shape it is, what wood it's made from, whether it's rotten, and how you throw it. Consider that a cudgel is just a sick and is deadly, as is a baseball bat. As are spears, boomerangs, cabers, and atlatls. Any piece of wood over around 1lb in weight that's thrown hard enough to travel 20-30' will be enough to kill someone if it hits them in the head in the right way.

Comment: What's an "atal"? I assume you meant [atlatl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spear-thrower)?

Comment: That's the correct spelling, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The lethality of an object depends on how much energy is applied to a given area of the body (whether it's enough to crack bone, or penetrate muscle to reach vital organs). Picking up a large log and throwing it at a relatively slow velocity is enough to kill someone if it crushes the skull or the ribcage. Since kinetic energy is mass times the *square* of velocity, most weapons are lighter, faster, and pointier — putting the maximum kinetic energy into the smallest possible area — but note that a car going as slow as 30 mph can kill someone with a crushing blow. No doubt a log at an equal speed could do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Archery.

You are describing an arrow. Also javelins fit the bill.

You can get the description on hunting bows as well as draw strength, expected arrow speed and weight.

As a rule of thumb, 40 pounds of kinetic energy efficiently kills whitetails, and 50 pounds or greater is required for larger game such as elk, moose or bear.

Comment: I actually meant with bare hands, if that is even possible to beginning with.

Comment: throwing != shooting with a bow

Comment: @topcode You're right but not quite what I wanted, as shooting bows require you to actually have a bow in the first place. I was just wondering if were to pick up a stick right now and throw it as hard as I can at someone could I actually kill them.

Comment: @Topcode sorry didn't realize you were saying the same thing as me. That is indeed what I meant, throwing doesn't equal shooting. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Then Javelines. That is a stick that kills.